# p:editor how to enable paste button

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have added PrimeFaces `p:editor` component on my form and defined controls for it like this:

```
<p:editor id="editorId" value="#{someBean.SomeText}" 
controls="bold italic paste pastetext" width="800" height="150" rows="6" 
disabled="#{not someBean.editorEnabled}" 
autoResize="false" onchange="submitSomething()" />
```

And as you can see in the attached image the paste button is disabled. So i wonder how can you enable this button?

[image: editor]

I'm running PrimeFaces 6.0 on WebSphere Application Server 8.5.

I get the same issue on primefaces showcase:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/editor.xhtml

using
Firefox 49.0.1 and Chrome 53.0.2785.143.

Comment: Nope. Its not working as you described in Firefox 49.0.1 neather in Chrome 53.0.2785.143

Comment: OOOOOPPPPPPSSSSS, does NOT work for me... I watched the the **copy button** (shame, shame)... Will remove my answer (and my comments) ;-)

Comment: It seems to be a bug. I've checked it on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE and... this is one of the case where something works only on IE :D (and probably on Egde)